# Site Regional Settings time zone vs User Profile time zone - how does this work

Tags: 2016, date-time

I'm working to define requirements for a site collection with 50+ sub-sites. The company is based in the Central Time zone. We will have internal and external users, but all will log in to access the site collection.

SharePoint is new to our company, so my IT team is relying on an outside firm to do the initial set up. I'm having a hard time understanding what I'm being told about time zones.

We will have a calendar for each site in the site collection. There will be a date/time field with both date and time for the start of each event. My understanding is that SharePoint stores all date/time as UTC.

If we set the site regional settings for all sites to be Central Time and a user is in Eastern Time, what will the user see?

What changes could a user with standard contribute permissions make which would change what time was displayed?

Comment: **What changes could a user with standard contribute permissions make which would change what time was displayed?**, means the user with contribute permissions can change the time zone what he wants to see.

Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the Regional settings at a site level everyone will see the same in your case central time. If the user is in eastern zone and wants to see in his zone he has to change his regional settings. This change will override the site settings to that user.

You refer the [MSDN article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-regional-settings-for-a-site-e9e189c7-16e3-45d3-a090-770be6e83c1a) for information on this.